# How to programatically start an EJB Timer from outside the Thread

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, ejb

I have an EJB timer that runs twice a day at specific times of the day.
I would like to be able to fire this timer manually by a request from a web page, but I don't see how this can be done.

I don't want to have this run in the Web's thread as the timer could be a long process, so it would be better to have it run in the EJB process in the background. I can get the `TimerService` inside the EJB, but I don't have access to it from the web context.

I have to use a timer and not a thread.
I am using JBoss 7 and also WebSphere 8.5 .

Answer (score 0):

We have 3 options to automatically create timer when application is deployed.

1. Create the timer by invoking the EJB method: Invoke `initializeTimer`
   in the `contextInitialized` method of a `ServletContextListener` of a web
   module.
2. Create a servlet and implement the init method to invoke the EJB
   method that creates the timer. Set the `load-on-startup` property for
   the servlet to automatically start the servlet when the web module is
   started.
3. Use a Startup class using the proprietary API of your J2EE container.

Here is an example how you can automatically schedule a timer using `ServletContextListener`(Option 1) when your application is deployed as follows:

```
public class MyLifeCycleEventExample
    implements ServletContextListener
{
    ServletContext servletContext;

        /* Methods from the ServletContextListener */
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)
    {
        servletContext = sce.getServletContext();
            try
    {
      Context context = new InitialContext();
      TimerDemoHome timerDemoHome =
          (TimerDemoHome)PortableRemoteObject.narrow(
              context.lookup("java:comp/env/TimerDemo"),
              TimerDemoHome.class);
      TimerDemo timerDemo;

      // Use one of the create() methods below to
      // create a new instance
      timerDemo = timerDemoHome.create();
      Date firstDate= new java.util.Date();

      // Call any of the Remote methods below to access
      // the EJB this code does not check whether the timer
      // has already been scheduled.
      // You should check this for duplicate timers
      timerDemo.initializeTimer( firstDate, 1800000, "MyTimer" );

      timerDemo.getTimerInfo();
      //Cancel Timer
      //timerDemo.cancelTimer("MyTimer");

    }
    catch(Throwable ex)
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)
    {
    }

          protected void log(String msg)
    {
          System.out.println("[" + getClass().getName() +
                             "] " + msg);
    }

}
```

but you need to register the listener in the deployment descriptor of your web module (web.xml) using below configuration

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>
      TimerWeb.MyLifeCycleEventExample
   </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you refactor and split the EJB?

EjbTimer gets invoked based on it's regular schedule.  The EjbTimer sends an asynch message to an MdbWorker which handles the long running process.

Then from a web page there could be a simple servlet which also knows how to generate the message (some shared code with EjbTimer) which is picked up by EjbWorker.  Since the message is asynch the web thread returns immediately.

Would it be okay to have concurrent long running instances?  If not, then you should probably set the MdbWorker as only 1 instance (somewhere in the jboss/WAS config).

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to the EJB that has your existing timeOut method which calls [javax.ejb.TimerService.createSingleActionTimer(long duration, TimerConfig config)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html#createSingleActionTimer-long-javax.ejb.TimerConfig-) with a short duration (10ms maybe?):

```
@Stateless // or @Singleton
public class MyTimerEJB {

    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    @Timeout
    public void existingTimeoutMethod() {
       ...
    }

    public void fireTimeoutAsynchronouslyAlmostImmediately() {
        timerService.createSingleActionTimer(10, new TimerConfig(null, false));
    }

}
```

Then just call this method from your page controller.

Edit: @S. Kadakov's solution is better if you're in a Java EE 6+ environment.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy:

```
import javax.ejb.Asynchronous;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

/**
 *
 * @author s.kadakov
 */
@Stateless
public class TimerBean {

    @Schedule(hour = "*/12", minute = "0", second = "0")
    public void longTermJob() {
        // do something
    }

    @Asynchronous
    public void fireJob() {
        longTermJob();
    }
}
```

Then just inject TimerBean into you servlet:

```
@EJB
private TimerBean timerBean;

...

timerBean.fireJob()
```